# launch website url with array when value is empty

Tags: php, arrays, iframe

I am trying to make a little search game and i am creating a command line that opens websites in a iframe, in the middle of the page (i didn't add this iframe yet to the page). I must say that the command line field is also in an iframe.

You can see and test the page here: http://www.josdenhertog.nl/tnes/getin.php

Now the problem:

When you just use your mouse and just press it so that you see the cursor at the start in the text field and you press ENTER on your keyboard without typing any command in this line, then it goes black on the iframe and do not load anything.

This is the code what i have so far:

```
$urlList = array ('test'  => 'commandline.php',
                  '  '  => 'commandline.php',
                  ' '  => 'commandline.php'
                   );      

if (isset ($_POST['command']) && strlen($_POST['command']) > 0) {

    # See if the command provided by the user exists in the list.
  if (array_key_exists ($_POST['command'], $urlList)) {

       #When Command exist.
    header ("Location: " . $urlList[$_POST['command']]);
  }
  else {
    # Command not found
    header ("Location: commandline.php");
  }
 }
```

My question is now:

How do i make that when you press only ENTER without typing anything in the command line, load up ONLY the commandline.php webpage. Like that array variable: $urlList

I am terrible when it comes on questions, hopefully you understand what i mean :)

Comment: i forgot to say, when you press accidently on the logout link. It will return you to a login screen. Then just type on both fields: test

Then you will return to the page where you was :)

Answer (score 0):

You need another `else` at the very end presumably. This will redirect back to commandline.php when $_POST['command'] is not set, or strlen() is <=0.

```
$urlList = array ('test'  => 'commandline.php',
                  '  '  => 'commandline.php',
                  ' '  => 'commandline.php'
                   );      

if (isset ($_POST['command']) && strlen($_POST['command']) > 0) {

    # See if the command provided by the user exists in the list.
  if (array_key_exists ($_POST['command'], $urlList)) {

       #When Command exist.
    header ("Location: " . $urlList[$_POST['command']]);
  }
  else {
    # Command not found
    header ("Location: commandline.php");
  }
 } else {
    header ("Location: commandline.php");
 }

 die();
```

Comment: Calling `isset($_POST['command'])` is sufficient. You don't need to call the `strlen` function on it, as `isset()` returns true only if it is not null.

Comment: Thx for fast response

Comment: @RPM I know, but that's not my code to be messing with, it's from the original :}

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of the code shown above, all you need is an else statement since your check for command string length and isset are the ones behind your issue:

```
else {
    header ("Location: commandline.php");
}
```